# user--register.tpl - show validation error messages

Tags: 7, theming, users, forms

I have overwritten theme of registration form using the file user--register.tpl
But when have some validation in the form, I cannot see error messages. 
How can I display error messages generated with form_set_error in validation callback?

The variable $messages is not set in this template by default.

Thanks for any help
Tomas

Comment: Was it working before you overriden it? What have you changed between default and your version?